# Variables within AWS Lambda Payload

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function I need to invoke from the command line. For the payload, I am passing a JSON style object with three unique key/value pairs.

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name .. --payload '{.....}'
```

Every time I invoke, the keys in that payload will be the same, however the associated values will be different.

What is not optional is that this needs to be invoked (for now) from the command line. So no console solutions will work at this very moment. Instead of re-typing the updates values each time I need to invoke (which is a few times per day), what is my best option for handling this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you compute the json message from Bash? If so, you would a script that concatenate the message component and using cron, execute command at desired times.

Comment: Is there a way you can generate new updated variables in command line? With bash or some scripting language?

Comment: Well, moreso I can save the payload as a json beforehand. If I did this, how might I read it in and then pass it as the --payload? Could this be a shell script?

Comment: `aws lambda invoke --function-name .. --payload '\`cat file.json\`'`